# How to filled svg color when i scrollling page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, fill

How to filled svg color (example red) follow svg when i scrollling page.
I show example svg, i want follow filled color svg when i scroll page.

```
<https://jsbin.com/wutozubezi/edit?html,js,output>
```

Comment: I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding the question. Do you mean that you want the SVG to be repeated across the page? So it's essentially a tiled background?

Comment: I want the svg to fill up red color as the page scrolls

Comment: That makes sense. What you tried/researched so far?

Comment: I trying https://jsbin.com/wokorifuxa/1/edit?html,js,output but not working .. this behavior weird

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to get you started.

Previously the `calcScrollPercent` function just returned where the window was scrolled to. I've changed that to return the percent:

```js
var calcScrollPercent = () => {
    var scrollMax = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var scrollPercent = document.documentElement.scrollTop / scrollMax;
    return scrollPercent;
}
```

Next I've changed the `drawWhenScroll` function to change the opacity of the SVG image based on how far the user has scrolled down the page:

```js
var drawWhenScroll = () => {
    var amount = 0.1 + (calcScrollPercent() * 0.9);  
    d3.selectAll('.scrollprogress').attr('opacity', amount);
}
```

Then thirdly I've made loads of changes to the page. Primarily so that the SVG is now output in red, but I've also changed the opacity of objects, added [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) to allow for easier editing of the page, etc.

All of those additions/changes are below. Run that, then scroll down and you'll see the SVG becomes more red.

I appreciate this won't exactly match what you're going for, because you haven't specified what you want. It is designed as a starting point for you to use and modify into the finished page.

```js
var drawWhenScroll = () => {
    var amount = 0.1 + (calcScrollPercent() * 0.9);  
    d3.selectAll('.scrollprogress').attr('opacity', amount);
}

var calcScrollPercent = () => {
    var scrollMax = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var scrollPercent = document.documentElement.scrollTop / scrollMax;
    return scrollPercent;
}
    
window.addEventListener('scroll', drawWhenScroll);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">  
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-0x7/VCkKLLt4wnkFqI8Cgv6no+AaS1TDgmHLOoU3hy/WVtYta2J6gnOIHhYYDJlDxPqEqAYLPS4gzVex4mGJLw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div className="xx">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="70"
          height="1237.521"
          viewBox="0 0 70 1237.521"
          class="scrollprogress"
          opacity="0.1"
        >
          <g
            id="Group_301"
            data-name="Group 301"
            transform="translate(-925 -698.432)"
          >
            <g id="Group_35" data-name="Group 35">
              <path
                    id="logo"
         
                data-name="Path 18"
                d="M980.8,407.46,980.7,180.085V1199.813l27.193,29.089H953.251L980.7,1257.84v159.766"
                transform="translate(-21 518.348)"
                fill="none"
                stroke="red"
                stroke-width="3"
              />
              <g
                id="Ellipse_12"
                data-name="Ellipse 12"
                transform="translate(951 1709.348)"
                fill="#fff"
                stroke="red"
                stroke-width="3"
              >
                <circle cx="8.5" cy="8.5" r="7" stroke="red" fill="white" />
              </g>
              <g
                id="Ellipse_13"
                data-name="Ellipse 13"
                transform="translate(978 1738.348)"
                fill="#fff"
                stroke="red"
                stroke-width="3"
              >
                <circle cx="8.5" cy="8.5" r="7" stroke="red" fill="white" />
              </g>
              <g
                id="Ellipse_11"
                data-name="Ellipse 11"
                transform="translate(925 1738.348)"
                fill="#fff"
                stroke="red"
                stroke-width="3"
              >
                <circle cx="8.5" cy="8.5" r="7" stroke="red" fill="white" />
              </g>
              <g
                id="Ellipse_16"
                data-name="Ellipse 16"
                transform="translate(951.07 1767.348)"
                fill="#fff"
                stroke="red"
                stroke-width="3"
              >
                <circle cx="8.5" cy="8.5" r="7" stroke="red" fill="white" />
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div className="xx">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="70"
          height="1237.521"
          viewBox="0 0 70 1237.521"
          class="scrollprogress"
          opacity="0.1"
        >
          <g
            id="Group_301"
            data-name="Group 301"
            transform="translate(-925 -698.432)"
          >
            <g id="Group_35" data-name="Group 35">
              <path
                id="logo"
                data-name="Path 18"
                d="M980.8,407.46,980.7,180.085V1199.813l27.193,29.089H953.251L980.7,1257.84v159.766"
                transform="translate(-21 518.348)"
                fill="none"
                stroke="red"
                stroke-width="3"
              />
              <g
                id="Ellipse_12"
                data-name="Ellipse 12"
                transform="translate(951 1709.348)"
                fill="#fff"
                stroke="red"
                stroke-width="3"
              >
                <circle cx="8.5" cy="8.5" r="7" stroke="red" fill="white" />
              </g>
              <g
                id="Ellipse_13"
                data-name="Ellipse 13"
                transform="translate(978 1738.348)"
                fill="#fff"
                stroke="red"
                stroke-width="3"
              >
                <circle cx="8.5" cy="8.5" r="7" stroke="red" fill="white" />
              </g>
              <g
                id="Ellipse_11"
                data-name="Ellipse 11"
                transform="translate(925 1738.348)"
                fill="#fff"
                stroke="red"
                stroke-width="3"
              >
                <circle cx="8.5" cy="8.5" r="7" stroke="red" fill="white" />
              </g>
              <g
                id="Ellipse_16"
                data-name="Ellipse 16"
                transform="translate(951.07 1767.348)"
                fill="#fff"
                stroke="red"
                stroke-width="3"
              >
                <circle cx="8.5" cy="8.5" r="7" stroke="red" fill="white" />
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```